# Is there a way to rotate a <canvas> element and treat the input as its rotated value?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a canvas with ID `foobar`. I've already drawn to it.

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("foobar");
```

I need to rotate this canvas 90°. Rotating `#foobar` with CSS doesn't work:

```css
#foobar {
  /* When I click somewhere on the canvas, it registers the position of the click
     as what the position would be pre-rotation rather than post-rotation. */
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

In addition, rotating the context only works when an element has yet to be drawn, so this won't work either:

```js
let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.rotate(90 * (Math.PI / 180));
```

Comment: canvas make fixed images, there no way for rotate only a part of this image. redraw your entire image with this rotated element, or use SVG

Answer (score 0):

When registering clicks, try to use `event.offsetX` and `event.offsetY`. These should line up properly with the canvas coordinates. For example:

```html
<canvas>
</canvas>

<style>
   canvas {
      transform: rotate(90deg);
      /* just so the canvas is visible */
      border-color: black;
      border-style: solid;
   }
</style>

<script>
   // when canvas is clicked, draw a dot
   const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
   const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   canvas.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      const x = e.offsetX;
      const y = e.offsetY
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
      ctx.fill();
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Ah, that helps - thanks! (Can't mark your answer as correct for another few minutes.)